# Different Field source for different Language

Tags: content-editor, templates, fieldtype

Is it possible to assign different field source for the different language?

For example, I have a sample template in with samplefield.

- samplefield has a field source as  `/sitecore/content/Home-en` for **English**.
- samplefield has field source as  `/sitecore/content/Home-ot` for **Other Languages**.

If not, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the requirement by either implementing a custom field or a custom token. I would tend to use the custom token

**Custom Token**

Below is the code snippet you can use to implement the custom token

```
public class CustomTokenReplacer : ExpandInitialFieldValueProcessor
{
    private const string Token = "$customtoken";

    public override void Process(ExpandInitialFieldValueArgs args)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

      // TODO: Add your own custom token replacement logic here...
    }
}
```

Then you patch the newly created token via the config file

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <expandInitialFieldValue>
        <processor type="YourNamespace, YourAssembly" patch:after="processor[@type='type=Sitecore.Pipelines.ExpandInitialFieldValue.ReplaceVariables, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
      </expandInitialFieldValue>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Note that in the datasource on your template, you should use the token you defined. Example: `$customtoken`

More information is available [here](https://soen.ghost.io/working-with-custom-tokens-in-sitecore/).