# Source Query using the current language version

Tags: multilingual, sitecore-query

I have a source query over a standard Multi-List field and I want the query to retrieve items based on the current selected language.

Is there any attribute that could handle that in the source query?

Comment: Hi Tareq - welcome to SSE. Is that a standard `Multilist` or a `Multilist with Search` ?

Comment: @RichardSeal standard Multilist

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13587/different-field-source-for-different-language/13588#13588. You can use custom token to change the source

Comment: @HishaamNamooya This could be very useful, I'm trying now

Comment: @HishaamNamooya What I want is that I have multilist that shows all items to select from, however I need to show only items that has a version of the currently selected language, at first I thought this could be done by the source query however there is no @@language attribute, do you have any idea?

Comment: @TareqMansour please see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OOTB Sitecore, this is not possible using Sitecore queries because Sitecore does not take into account which language has been selected.

**Get Lookup Source Item**

You can use the Lookup Source Item pipeline (`<getLookupSourceItems>`). This particular pipeline is responsible to execute the Sitecore query you've filled in the Datasource Field. Moreover, you can implement your business logic to retrieve items.

**Implementation**

You will need to implement a method which has `GetLookupSourceItemsArgs` as parameter. The `args` paramter has a property named **Item** which contain the selected item in the current selected version.

```
public void Process(GetLookupSourceItemsArgs args)
{
    if (this.SkipProcessor(args)) return;

    var items = Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem("PATH TO CONTAINER ITEM OR SITECORE ID"), args.Item.Language).GetChildren(ChildListOptions.SkipSorting);

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var itemVersions = item.Versions.GetVersions();

        foreach (var itemVersion in itemVersions)
        {
            if (itemVersion.Language.Name.Equals(args.Item.Language.Name))
            {
                args.Result.Add(itemVersion);
            }
        }
    }

    args.AbortPipeline();
}

private bool SkipProcessor(GetLookupSourceItemsArgs args)
{
    return !args.Source.ToLower().Contains("itemversionspecific");
}
```

**Configuration File**

Once you implemented the code, you need to add it to the `getLookupSourceItems` pipeline. Below is an example of the patch.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getLookupSourceItems>
        <processor type="YourNamespace,YourAssembly" patch:before="*"/>
      </getLookupSourceItems>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Testing**

Based on the above code, I tested it by creating a container item named `Items` holding 3 items

1. Item with English version only
2. Item with French version only
3. Item with both English and French version

**English Version Selected**
[image]

**French Version Selected**
[image]

Upon selection of a language version, the items from the Multi-List Field changes the list of items.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Hishaam you are awesome :)